# instagram Authentication gives 'No matching code found' when I use additional query parameters

Tags: yii, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

instagram Authentication gives 'No matching code found' only when I use additional query parameters:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://dev.dev-site.ru/?reg=1&response_type=code
```

If I use it without additional parameter all is ok:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://dev.dev-site.ru/&response_type=code
```

I tried to change registered REDIRECT URI to "http://dev.dev-site.ru/", "http://dev.dev-site.ru/?reg" but unsuccessfully. What is is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The `?` in `redirect_uri` is causing issues, URL escape the `redirect_uri` value and it will work fine.

Comment: Instagram API documentation says that "http://yourcallback.com/?this=that" is valid "REDIRECT_URI PARAMETER PASSED TO /AUTHORIZE" but it doesn't work. Proof link https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/